# How to find existence of some value in DOM using JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can i iterate the following DOM and to find if some `li` has the value of `Value2 is here`

i would like to have some boolean function such as

```
var v = IsValueExist('Value2 is here')

<div class="span6">
    <ol id="sortable1" class="rectangle-list">
        <li><a href="#">Value1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Value2 is here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Value3 is here</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like:

```
if ($('#sortable1 > li:contains("Value2 is here")').length > 0) {
  //found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/
But it will return both `<a href="#">Value2 is here</a>` and `<a href="#">Value2 is here again</a>`

As an alternative, you may do next:

```
var lis = $("#sortable1 li").filter(function(index){ $(this).text() == "some text"});
if(lis.length > 0) {
  //sortable1  contains an element with "some text" inside
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/